# Formatting awk output

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am trying using format the output from awk such that the output is delimited by comma. 
Right now I have this:

```
ids ="`smartctl -A /dev/ssd |awk '/^[0-9]/ {if ($4 < $6) {print $1}}'`"
```

and my output looks like this:

```
111
222
333
```

but I want something like this:

```
111,222,333
```

Also my regex doesn't match with numbers 1 to 99, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
your command|awk...|paste -s -d','
```

e.g:

```
kent$  paste -s -d',' <<< "a
b
c
d"
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed your `awk` command to use `printf`:

```
smartctl -A /dev/ssd |awk '/^[0-9]/ {if ($4 < $6){printf "%s%s",sep,$1;sep=","}}'
```

If you want a trailing newline throw `END{print ""}` on the end.